# In Excel, how can I conditionally cut a row of data and move it to another worksheet permanantly?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, vba

I have a worksheet with all my projects listed.  When I have marked one row (project) as "Finaled" from a drop down in column D, I want the entire row to be moved to my "Finaled" worksheet and permanantly stay on that worksheet.

I have basic programming knowledge, and have come up with this Macro...

```
    Sub Finaled()
    Dim i, LastRow

    Sheets("FINALED").Range("A2:Z500").ClearContents
    For i = 19 To LastRow
    If Sheets("ACTIVE").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Finaled" Then
    Sheets("ACTIVE").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("FINALED").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

...but this isn't working exactly like I want it to. The first problem is it only copies the row of information, and when I manually delete the row from my main worksheet, the next time I run the Macro, I lose the originally copied rows of data on my Finaled worksheet.  I want it to completely cut the row of data and move it to my "Finaled" worksheet, and keep it there permanently.

Second, can this move happen automatically as soon as I mark the row as "finaled" from my drop down list in column D?  Or do I have to manually run the Macro everytime?

Comment: What do you mean by `it only copies the row of information, and when I delete rows from the original worksheet, the data is lost on the finale sheet`? If you copy data to the final sheet then the data is there and should not vanish if you delete something on another sheet. For your section question you might want to look into the [Worksheet_Change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx).

Comment: What I mean is the row of data is essentially "copied and pasted" onto my finaled worksheet, and it still remains on my main worksheet as well.  I don't want the row of data copied, I want it cut from my main worksheet and input on my finaled worksheet.  2nd part, once it appears on my finaled worksheet, I have been manually deleting it from my main worksheet.  But when I run the macro again, (since the row of data is no longer on the main worksheet) the finaled worksheet is updated and those rows of data I have deleted from the main worksheet no longer appear on the finaled worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the VBA Editor, doubleclick on your worksheet named `ACTIVE` and that will bring up that worksheet's code module (not that it is different from a standard module):

[image: Worksheet code module]

Then in that sheet module, paste the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngCheck As Range
    Dim rngChanged As Range
    Dim ChangedCell As Range
    Dim rngMove As Range

    Set wsData = Me
    Set wsDest = Me.Parent.Sheets("FINALED")
    Set rngCheck = wsData.Range("D19", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    If rngCheck.Row < 19 Then Exit Sub  'No data

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ReEnableEvents

    Set rngChanged = Intersect(rngCheck, Target)

    If Not rngChanged Is Nothing Then
        For Each ChangedCell In rngChanged.Cells
            If LCase(Trim(ChangedCell.Value)) = "finaled" Then
                Select Case (rngMove Is Nothing)
                    Case True:  Set rngMove = ChangedCell
                    Case Else:  Set rngMove = Union(rngMove, ChangedCell)
                End Select
            End If
        Next ChangedCell

        If Not rngMove Is Nothing Then
            With rngMove.EntireRow
                .Copy
                wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Delete xlShiftUp
            End With
        End If
    End If

ReEnableEvents:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Now when you change a cell in column D to "finaled" it will be automatically moved to the `FINALED` worksheet.

Also, the reason you were losing your data on the `FINALED` worksheet was because of this line: `Sheets("FINALED").Range("A2:Z500").ClearContents` which I have not included because I don't think you actually want that.

Comment: So, this worked great and I was so excited, until I closed it and reopened it.:/  I saved it and when I reopened the excel document, the "finaled" tab was completely blank.  I had actually "finaled" 27 projects which removed from the active tab and appeared on the finaled tab just like I wanted them to.  Any ideas why they disappeared when I reopened the document?

Comment: There is no reason they would have disappeared unless you have another macro that runs on `workbook_open`, `workbook_close` or `sheet_activate` or similar that would have cleared the data (such as the aforementioned `ClearContents` line).